# How to hide the first tag of a certain type on a page

Tags: javascript, css

Is there anyway to select the first instance of a tag on a page?

I'm using Drupal and the client is changing one field to another, but temporarily needs both fields (due to events created with the old field, and ongoingly, for new events), however they only want one to display.

I want to make it so that the first instance of the `<label>content</label>` and the `<span class="date-display-single">content</span>` are not visible.

Comment: Does psuedo selector css doesn't solve ur problem??

You can use first-child or first-of -type

Comment: Show us some code. Perhaps the context will give a clue to solve your problem.

Comment: $('label').first().prop('hidden', 'true')
$('span.date-display-single').first().prop('hidden', 'true')

if i've understood you correct, this will help, but it's no very relayable

Answer (score 2):

CSS only (I don't know if this is suitable for you):

```
label:first-of-type, .date-display-single:first-of-type {
  display: none;
}
```

If you must support older versions of browsers, which don't support the `:first-of-type` pseudo class, you can go with the vanilla JS solution proposed by KingKongFrog

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0].style.display = 'none';
document.getElementsByClassName("date-display-single")[0].style.display = 'none';
```